# Luggage Transfer Service damaged luggage

Tags: spain, damaged-luggage

A friend of mine recently travelled on the Camino de Santiago in Spain and used a luggage transfer service to move their suitcase from one town to the next. On the penultimate leg of the journey, the suitcase arrived damaged - the section around one of the wheels was cracked and bent.

My friend informed the company of what had happened and, after a few weeks of deliberation, the company offered €20 compensation for the damage. The suitcase was purchased for around €58 for which my friend has the receipt. They asked the company to reimburse for the cost of a new suitcase as they feel they will need to replace their current one. The company argued that since the damage is localized to a small area, the compensation should be partial.

**Is the company being fair in this instance?

Does my friend have any option other than to accept/decline the compensation?

Is there a higher authority to whom they can appeal (analogous to UK body ABTA)?**

Apologies in advance if this is the wrong forum for this type of question.

**Edit to answer some questions in the comments.**

- The suitcase is still "usable", can be packed and carried, although it is vulnerable where damaged and doesn't really travel on its wheels.
- With regard to travel insurance, I'm not sure but I think my friend said that the excess is either on or close to the cost of the suitcase.
- The suitcase is less than a year old and was in good condition (like new).
- Terms and conditions mention scratches and missing handles not being covered, but loss is. It's a little vague about the in between cases.

Comment: Is the suitcase still usable?

Comment: Do you happen to have a travel insurance that may be able to cover the damage?

Comment: What do the company’s T&C say? How old is the suitcase and what condition was it in when it was handed over to the luggage transfer company? Is it still useable? TBH for something that only cost €58 I doubt there is any recourse

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've edited the question to try and answer these - my feeling is that maybe my friend should just accept the offer.

Comment: Most travel operators will have in their conditions some wording saying that luggage should be able to endure normal handling. Like if you bring a half-empty cardboard box, it will definitely not be able to endure anything being piled upon it or being subjected to rain. I’m sorry to say that a €58 suitcase is probably not the most durable thing ever, and that it does carry a risk of being damaged in normal handling. You can try to pursue it further, but the time, energy, and possible cost if you really want to take it to court will be much more than €38. Take the offer and cut your losses.